# Capturing requests from a local service using postman/fiddler during automated test

Tags: http, postman, fiddler

Hi guys I’m running some automated tests using spock groovy n intellij on a windows machine in order to test an api.

The set up is a s follows:
The service under test is running locally on port A. There is an additional mock service running on port B.

During my test scenarios, the service under test sends a post request to the mock service which has been configured to respond with a 200 providing the service makes the specified post request. 
(The state of the mock service is controlled using wire mock)

Some of my tests are failing, however when make the expected post request using postman I get the expected 200 response.

Hence I would like to capture the post request content that gets sent by my service under test during a test run so that I can inspect and compare the content with what I am sending manually.

I’ve tried to capture the request by setting up a postman proxy on port 5555 and using fiddler.
This works fine  when I make the requests manually through the postman UI but it does not catch anything when I run my tests.
This is the first time trying to capture the request content from a local service and was wondering if anyone has done something similar before or has any advice on how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

to capture traffic from spock tests via Fiddler, add the following in your tests such as from setupSpec method

```
System.properties.putAll(['http.proxyHost':'localhost', 'http.proxyPort':'8888'])
```

To capture traffic from one service to other endpoints, you can start your service like so

**java -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -jar some_jar_file**

To capture traffic to a local endpoint, replacing localhost in the endpoint url with your computer name as a workaround because Fiddler will not capture local traffic.